# Show that $E_Q[Y]=E_P[XY]$

Tags: probability-theory

I was trying to solve an exercise which asks me to prove

Show that $E_Q[Y]=E_P[XY]$ where $P$ is a probability measure on $(\Omega,\mathcal{A})$ and $X$ is a r.v such that $P[X>0]=1$ and $E[X]=1 $

$Q:\mathcal{A} \to R$ is a probability measure such that

$Q(A)=E[X\mathrm{1}_A]$

I managed to prove it using the standard technique where I first prove it for simple functions, then pass to positive functions via Beppo-Levi but nowhere in the proof do I use that $\{X>0\}$ has measure one(all I need is $X\ge 0$ almost surely). Where exactly is almost sure strict positivity used. Is it even required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not required; all you need for what you wish to prove is that $X \ge 0$ almost surely. However, the fact that $X > 0$ a.s. does guarantee that $P$ and $Q$ are equivalent measures. That is, they are mutually absolutely continuous, which is to say that $P \ll Q$ and $Q \ll P$. (It might be useful to think through why this is true.)

This then means that you also have that for each $A \in \mathcal A$, $$P(A) = E_Q \left[\frac 1X 1_A\right],$$ so that, for every $P$-integrable $Y$, $$ E_P[Y] = E_Q \left[ \frac YX \right]. $$